# Dimension of set of hyperplanes containing a line

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Consider a line $r$ in a projective space $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. I'd like to understand what is the dimension of the set of hypersurfaces containing $r$, that is
$$\dim(M_r)=\dim\{H\subset \mathbb{P}^{n-1}\mid \dim(H)=n-2 \text{, and} H\supset r\}.$$
This question arises from my research, but I'm new to these kind of probelms and I'd like to understand if I'm correct.

In order to familiarize with it, I tried the case $n=4$, that is $\mathbb{P}^3$: wlog I assumed $r=Z(x_2,x_3)$. But if $H$ contains the line, I must impose only another condition to describe the plane, hence I obtain $M_r\simeq \mathbb{C}\simeq \mathbb{P}^0$.

Thus I suspect that in general, for a line in $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ I obtain $M_r\simeq \mathbb{C}^{n-3}\simeq \mathbb{P}^{n-2}$.

I apologize in advance if my reasoning was quite rude, but I did not know how to approach it. Moreover, does there exists a general strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have a line $L\subset\mathbb P^3$, a plane $H_p \supset L$ is determined by picking a point $p\in\mathbb P^3 \setminus L$, but for any $p$ there is a $\mathbb P^2 \setminus L$ worth of points $q$ such that $H_p = H_q$. In other words, there is a surjective map $\mathbb P^3 \setminus L \to M_r$ with $2$-dimensional fibers, so $\dim (M_L) = 1$.

If you have $L \subset \mathbb P^4$, you need to pick a general line to get a hyperplane. The Grassmannian $G(2,5)$ of lines in $\mathbb P^4$ has dimension $2(5-2) = 6$, while the Grassmannian $G(2,4)$ of lines in a $3$-plane has dimension $4$. Thus we have a surjective map from an open subset of the first Grassmannian onto $M_L$ with $4$-dimensional fibers, hence $\dim (M_L) = 2$.

In general, this setup produces a surjection from an open subset of $G(n-3,n)$ onto $M_L$ whose fibers are isomorphic to an open subset of $G(n-3,n-1)$, so the target has dimension $(n-3)(n-(n-3)) - (n-3)(n-1 - (n-3)) = (n-3)(3) - (n-3)(2) = n-3$.

Comment: Dear @Tabes Bridge, thanks for the  nice answer! Before accpeting it, I have some quesstions: what do you mean by "woth of points"? in the last paragraph, you consider a $G(n-3,n)$ becuase then the union with a line will produce a general hyperplane, right? finally, in my case -that is, $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$, we obtain $n-4$, right? Thanks again and have a nice day!

Comment: (sorry, another dumb question: when you talk about dimension, you mean it as a complex vector space, right?)

Comment: First, I just mean that the space of points $q$ such that $H_q = H_p$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^2 \setminus L$. You are correct about why I considered that Grasssmannian, but I was working in your case the whole time. I'm using affine dimensions in my Grassmannian notation, so e.g. $G(2,n) \cong \mathbb G(1,n-1)$ is the space of lines in $\mathbb P^{n-1}$.

Comment: I mean dimension as a complex algebraic variety ($M_L$ is not a vector space), which is basically what you mean since a complex vector space can be thought of as a variety, and the notions of dimension coincide.